# changing color of bootstrap navbar links on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap Navigation bar, I want to change the color of the links in the navigation bar, on hover. I have tried CSS for it but it is not working.
I don't want to change the code, but within the same  tag classes I want to add the effect. Some people use lists for the navigation bar, I don't want to do so.

I have tried to add CSS for the same for the hover with class defined in the each  tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <div class="container-fullwidth">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
                <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                            <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I want to to have a green color on services when I hover on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.services-link strong:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fullwidth">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
      <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
          <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **This is your solution**

```css
.navbar-nav .services-link:hover{
color: #7FFF00 !important; /* your color */
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fullwidth">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hover` for service link it will works

```css
.services-link:hover{
color:#00ff00 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fullwidth">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it specifically on service, add an id to the Services 
`<a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" id="services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>`

and then in your css file add this

```
#services-link:hover {
color: green;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and have tried again this did not work.

Comment: That could be because under 
        .nav-item:hover  you have an !important  placed on your red color declaration that overrides the code. If not, check the hierarchy of how your css is being declared to make sure it is all placed in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">

    <style>
        .nav-item:hover {
            color: red !important;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fullwidth">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand">
                <strong>Digitian Hub</strong>
            </h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu"
                aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html">
                        <strong>Home</strong>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#">
                        <strong>Services</strong>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html">
                        <strong>Contact Us</strong>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is totally different sir, It is not working as per  need

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution;

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <div class="container-fullwidth">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
                <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                            <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <style>
                .services-link:hover{
                    color: green !important;
                }
            </style>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add below **CSS** for adding hover to navigation and add after **bootstrap CSS** in header

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.services-link:hover {
  color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="contact.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.services-link:hover {
    color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
  }
</style>
        
        <div class="container-fullwidth">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success fixed-top">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand"><strong>Digitian Hub</strong></h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NewMenu" aria-label="toggleNavigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NewMenu">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="Rishabh.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link services-link" href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a>
                        <a class="nav-item active nav-link contact-link" href="Contact Us.html"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```